# Animate UIViews like iPad photos application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation, core-animation

I want to make an application like photos of iPad in which it displays photos in grid manner and after clicking over custom-view it animated from its current position.
I just want to know how to animate view from its current position like if i click over the custom-view which is first line then it will show that custom-view animating from top position and if i click over the custom-view which is in bottom line then it will show and animate custom-view from bottom position and same for middle line also. Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i tried [UIView beginAnimation] which shows view directly but i want it from current point of view and that current point could be either starting or ending or middle.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the from value then the current value is the default. If you still want to specify the default value then the current frame of the image would probably do.

Depending on what happens next in your application and if the images resize or not you may need to animate a transform as well. Otherwise just animating the frame from its current value to [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; will be a good starting point.

Also, depending on where your image is in the view hierarchy you may need to move it to appear on top of tab bars and navigation bars if you truly want the image to appear full-screen when tapped.

Comment: i am talkin about view should get animate not image

Comment: I was just assuming that it was an image since you talked about the photos app. The frame (or transform) animations is the same for an view though. You animate from the current frame to the full screen frame (if that is what you want)

Comment: i want to display view from current point to full screen just like zooming but the animation should be from current point